# Wifi issue with either 16.04 or 18.04 on Thinkpad x230

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, intel-wireless

Bought refurbushed x230. Came with Windows 10 and am trying to set up as dual boot. Everything works find except wireless which constantly asks for a password. Same problem on 16.04 and 18.04. Currently on 16.04 and below is some info..

iwconfig

```
wlp3s0 IEEE 802.11 ESSID:off/any
       MOde:Managed Access Point: Not Associated Tx-Power=15 dBm
       Retry Short Limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr: off
       Power Management:on
```

lspci -v

```
03+00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 (rev C4)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 BGN
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kenrel modules: iwlwifi
```

rfkill list

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
```

/var/log/syslog

```
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3090] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'dd-wrt' (18444742-1f65-43b5-9082-fac424c611dc)
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3092] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="18444742-1f65-43b5-9082-fac424c611dc" name="dd-wrt" pid=1777 uid=1000 result="success"
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3093] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3095] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3100] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3103] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'dd-wrt' has security, but secrets are required.
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3104] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3159] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3163] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3166] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'dd-wrt' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3167] Config: added 'ssid' value 'dd-wrt'
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3167] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3168] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3168] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3168] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3265] sup-iface[0xa048e68,wlp3s0]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.3487] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 (SSID='dd-wrt' freq=2462 MHz)
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134754.287238] wlp3s0: authenticate with 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134754.291255] wlp3s0: send auth to 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 (try 1/3)
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 (SSID='dd-wrt' freq=2462 MHz)
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134754.295810] wlp3s0: authenticated
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.8850] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134754.299117] wlp3s0: associate with 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 (try 1/3)
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.8882] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134754.305391] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: Associated with 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134754.323799] wlp3s0: associated
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223399.9136] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Sep 17 18:29:59 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134754.396404] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81
Sep 17 18:30:03 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134758.352461] wlp3s0: disassociated from 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 reason=2
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <warn>  [1537223404.0154] sup-iface[0xa048e68,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason 2)
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223404.0200] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223404.1202] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 5c:a9:33:02:a8:fa (SSID='dd-wrt' freq=2412 MHz)
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134758.573105] wlp3s0: authenticate with 5c:a9:33:02:a8:fa
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134758.576179] wlp3s0: send auth to 5c:a9:33:02:a8:fa (try 1/3)
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 5c:a9:33:02:a8:fa (SSID='dd-wrt' freq=2412 MHz)
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134758.582779] wlp3s0: authenticated
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223404.1718] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134758.587117] wlp3s0: associate with 5c:a9:33:02:a8:fa (try 1/3)
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223404.1754] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134758.619091] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 5c:a9:33:02:a8:fa (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=6)
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: Associated with 5c:a9:33:02:a8:fa
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134758.638103] wlp3s0: associated
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223404.2286] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Sep 17 18:30:04 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134758.691653] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 5c:a9:33:02:a8:fa
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134762.667740] wlp3s0: disassociated from 5c:a9:33:02:a8:fa (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=5c:a9:33:02:a8:fa reason=2
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <warn>  [1537223408.3024] sup-iface[0xa048e68,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason 2)
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223408.3077] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223408.4074] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 5c:a9:33:02:c2:22 (SSID='dd-wrt' freq=2437 MHz)
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134763.363665] wlp3s0: authenticate with 5c:a9:33:02:c2:22
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134763.368967] wlp3s0: send auth to 5c:a9:33:02:c2:22 (try 1/3)
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 5c:a9:33:02:c2:22 (SSID='dd-wrt' freq=2437 MHz)
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223408.9604] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134763.375258] wlp3s0: authenticated
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134763.376267] wlp3s0: waiting for beacon from 5c:a9:33:02:c2:22
Sep 17 18:30:08 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223408.9681] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223409.0902] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223409.1900] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 (SSID='dd-wrt' freq=2462 MHz)
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134764.098884] wlp3s0: authenticate with 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134764.104119] wlp3s0: send auth to 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 (try 1/3)
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 (SSID='dd-wrt' freq=2462 MHz)
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134764.107440] wlp3s0: authenticated
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134764.111020] wlp3s0: associate with 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 (try 1/3)
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223409.6964] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223409.6980] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134764.117620] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=2)
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: Associated with 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134764.136259] wlp3s0: associated
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223409.7260] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Sep 17 18:30:09 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134764.226814] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81
Sep 17 18:30:13 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134768.165959] wlp3s0: disassociated from 5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
Sep 17 18:30:13 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=5c:a9:33:02:a9:81 reason=2
Sep 17 18:30:13 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 wpa_supplicant[933]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Sep 17 18:30:13 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <warn>  [1537223413.8010] sup-iface[0xa048e68,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason 2)
Sep 17 18:30:13 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223413.8061] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Sep 17 18:30:13 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 NetworkManager[786]: <info>  [1537223413.9062] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 17 18:30:13 kscott-ThinkPad-X230 kernel: [134768.394844] wlp3s0: authenticate with 5c:a9:33:02:a8:fa
```

So, a bunch of repeating some of the above. I have searched high and low. I am not overly familiar with some of these messages so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!